# Using GetHashCode() on socket as temporally UniqueID

Tags: c#, sockets

Is GetHashCode() safe to use for this?

I have a socket server and then a client program where the client program connects to the server console application hosted on a server and then I add the Socket to a Session instance (Session.cs class) and in that class I have a string called

```
private readonly string uniqueSessionID; // UniqueID
```

Now all I need it to be unqiue for is the Socket untill I send a message with a permenant UniqueID

I am using the below function to get a permenant uniqueID on the client application

```
string machineID = string.Empty;

            ManagementObjectCollection mbsList = null;
            ManagementObjectSearcher mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_processor");
            mbsList = mbs.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in mbsList)
                machineID = mo["ProcessorID"].ToString();

            ManagementObject dsk = new ManagementObject(@"win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=""c:""");
            dsk.Get();

            machineID = machineID + dsk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
```

then sending it to the server, once the server receives it, it will replace `uniqueSessionID` string with the new ID and the temp uniqueID is only to identify for when I send the permenant one, I could use IP address but I am worried two people will connect under the same WIFI or some similar.

Bottom line the question is, is GetHashCode() safe? Will it stay the same for the period of about 30 seconds, connecting and sending the first message so I can identify the ID that was set when they connected when I send the first message?

Comment: You can only have one connection with the same 3 properties 1) Source IP Address 2) Destination IP 3) Port Number.  So a Socket Client will have unique [port, IP] for each remote connection.

Answer (score 0):

`GetHashCode` is safe to use - in sense it will not throw exceptions. There are really no other guarantees for this function to return stable value for types that are not designed as keys for `HashSet`/`Dictionary`.

For `Socket` type the value *likely* to stay the same but you should not rely on it.

It would be better to create unique ID (i.e. `Guid.NewGuid()`) and store it somewhere.